# ThreeJS: loading OBJ files keeping quadrilateral faces

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to load an OBJ file under ThreeJS keeping the quadrilateral faces? Here is an example:

http://www.professores.im-uff.mat.br/hjbortol/disciplinas/2014.2/hwc00001/test/threejs/viewer-04/viewer-04-b.html

Note that each quadrilateral face is rendered as two triangles in wireframe. I would like to keep the original quadrilateral faces, as shown here (in Java):

http://www.uff.br/cdme/triplets/triplets-html/triplets-en.html

And what about a general n-polygon face in OBJ files? Is it possible to keep it?

Thanks, Humberto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately everything gets translated to triangles. However, you may be able to achieve the results you are after with this code:

```
var edges = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh );
scene.add( edges );
```

Comment: Hi! THREE.EdgesHelper() doesn't work in ThreeJS r68. There is a bug (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5098) and the fix is still not incorporated in r68. Thanks!

Comment: Uops! Hope to be releasing r69 soon!